# PHP Extract numbers from a string

Tags: php, split, preg-match, substr, preg-split

**I want to extract numbers from a string in PHP like following :**

if the **string = 'make1to6'** i would like to extract the numeric character before and after the 'to' substring in the entire string. i.e. **1 and 6 are to be extracted**

i will be using these returned values for some calculations.' i would like to extract the numeric character before and after the 'to' substring in the entire string. i.e. 1 and 6 are to be extracted

The length of the string is not fixed and can be a max of 10 characters in length.The number can be of max two digits on either side of 'to' in the string.

Some example string values :

```
sure1to3
ic3to9ltd
anna1to6
joy1to4val
make6to12
ext12to36
```

thinking of something like :

```
function beforeTo(string) {

    return numeric_value_before_'to'_in_the_string;

}


function afterTo(string) {

    return numeric_value_after_'to'_in_the_string;

}
```

i will be using these returned values for some calculations.

Comment: Have you tried looping through each character and checking if it `is_int()`? (http://php.net/is_int)

Comment: I am confused.  Is this task about text extraction, text validation, or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression as such, it should match exactly your specification:

```
$string = 'make6to12';
preg_match('{^.*?(?P<before>\d{1,2})to(?P<after>\d{1,2})}m', $string, $match);
echo $match['before'].', '.$match['after']; // 6, 12
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `preg_match_all` to achive this:

```
function getNumbersFromString($str) {
    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all('/([0-9]+)/', $str, $matches);
    return $matches;
}
$matches = getNumbersFromString('hej 12jippi77');
```

Comment: This entire pattern could be simplified to `/\d+/`.  The capture group is unnecessary and `[0-9]` is more briefly expresses as `\d`.

Answer (score 1):

Use preg_match with a regex that will extract the numbers for you. Something like this should do the trick for you:

```
$matches = null;
$returnValue = preg_match('/([\d+])to([\d+])/uis', 'ic3to9ltd', $matches);
```

After this `$matches` will look like:

```
array (
  0 => '3to9',
  1 => '3',
  2 => '9',
);
```

You should read somewhat on regular expressions, it's not hard to do stuff like this if you know how they work. Will make your life easier. ;-)

Comment: tested with a string with two digits....  not working with two digits like "m6to12" but works for "m1to6"

Comment: The reason it fails with more than one digit is that it uses `[\\d+]` which really means one character of `0-9` or `+`, so it would also match a `+` which is really wrong. Simply writing `\d+` would match 1 or more characters of `0-9`, which would be better.

Comment: Wrapping `\d` in a character class is pointless.  The askers input does not suggest that case insensitive or multibyte matching is required.  The `s` modifier is pointless since there is no `.` in the pattern.  This answer is teaching plenty of bad pattern crafting practices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
// $str holds the string in question
if (preg_match('/(\d+)to(\d+)/', $str, $matches)) {
    $number1 = $matches[1];
    $number2 = $matches[2];
}
```

Comment: This works, but does not validate that there is only 1 or 2 digits before/after "to", see my answer below for a more strict approach.

Comment: @rabusmar - this works great... except it doesnt validate that the digits length should be either 1 or 2.... anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions.

```
$string = 'make1to6';
if (preg_match('/(\d{1,10})to(\d{1,10})/', $string, $matches)) {
    $number1 = (int) $matches[1];
    $number2 = (int) $matches[2];
} else {
    // Not found...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data = <<<EOF

sure1to3
ic3to9ltd
anna1to6
joy1to4val
make6to12
ext12to36

EOF;

preg_match_all('@(\d+)to(\d+)@s', $data, $matches);
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

//print_r($matches);
foreach($matches as $match)
{
    echo sprintf("%d, %d\n", $match[1], $match[2]);
}

?>
```

Comment: The `s` pattern modifier is useless because there is no `.` in the pattern

Answer (score 0):

This is what Regular Expressions are for - you can match multiple instances of very specific patterns and have them returned to you in an array.  It's pretty awesome, truth be told :)

Take a look here for how to use the built in regular expression methods  in php : [LINK](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

And here is a fantastic tool for testing regular expressions: [LINK](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Comment: There isn't much substance in this answer.  It could have been a comment under the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
list($before, $after) = explode('to', 'sure1to3');

$before_to = extract_ints($before);
$after_to  = extract_ints($after);

function extract_ints($string) {
    $ints = array();
    $len = strlen($string);

    for($i=0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        $char = $string{$i};
        if(is_numeric($char)) {
            $ints[] = intval($char);
        }
    }

    return $ints;
}
?>
```

A regex seems really unnecessary here since all you are doing is checking `is_numeric()` against a bunch of characters.

Comment: It seems entitely possible, to me, that `to` _could_ occur more than once in the string.